# Middleware not invoking when expected in .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my startup.cs file in my configure method I have the following:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: Create an exception handler controller...
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

     //   app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()); //required to force URL to https

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UsePartialPageRendering();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next.Invoke();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/user/sign-in");
            }
        });


        app.UseMvc();
        // Log the environment so we can tell if it is correct.
        Logger.LogInformation($"Hosting environment: {HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}");
    }
```

Then in an Authorisation filter I have some code and in some conditions I have:

```
var authorisationCookie = _httpContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Where(t => t.Key == "aut").FirstOrDefault();
        //no valid cookie
        if (authorisationCookie.Key == null)
        {
            //Kill the pipeline so that view doesn't get displayed.
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult(); //should be this, but trouble handling it client side.

            return;
        }
```

When this line is hit if I use google developer tools I can see that a 401 is correctly returned, but my pipeline above never gets hit. How do I need to change this so that anytime a 401 is raised from anywhere in my app, the redirect occurs?

Comment: At a guess: you're calling `.Use(...)` after you've called `.UseAuthentication(...)`

Comment: @John no I don't. I've embellished my question with part of my code for returning the 401

Comment: Can you show more of the code from Startup's Configure method?

Comment: @John Hi John I've updated my code to show the whole method

Comment: Can you try and reduce this down to a [mcve]? I've tried a project that does something similar with an `IAuthorizationFilter` and custom `Use(...)` and it works as expected.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Just wondering.... In my design, the filter is set on a method that is in a webapi project, and the config code is from the MVC front end project. I'm trying to keep this all separate since The authentication takes place on the api (so that if we change the front end out the core code still works). Hence the api throws a 401 which any client should catch. So thinking about it, they will be in different context's. But this must be a common issue (for which I've not found an answer yet, but it probably explains why it doesn't work for me)

Comment: So you have an MVC application that's communicating with a separate WebApi style MVC application? How exactly is it doing said communication? Is it using `HttpClient` to make requests, for example? It's not clear to me how these two different contexts are interacting.

Comment: @KirkLarkin I've realised they are not. Each have their own context. The web api is stateless so creates a new context each time it gets called. So I've answered my own question into why it's not working. My api should be agnostic hence I don't want to redirect anywhere specific from that I just want to return valid data or status codes etc. and then the front end should deal with the data or status codes. Just as a test I moved the code from the mvc startup to the api's startup, but it still didn't get hit. So  is how do I get the front end code to respond to any 401 returned by the api.